# Google Business Profile Performance API consistently returning 400 errors even though my tokens are properly set

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm having issues getting past a 400 error with very little detail included. I'm essentially trying to return a count of reviews for a business. Any guidance is extremely helpful.

```
const accessToken = user.auth_token;

async function fetchBusinessProfilePerformance() {
  try {
    console.log("=== Starting function ===");

    // Define the location ID for the business profile you want to fetch data for
    const locationId = user.locationId;

    // Calculate the start date as 1 month ago from today
    const startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
    const formattedStartDate = startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];

    // Calculate the end date as today
    const endDate = new Date();
    const formattedEndDate = endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];

    // Define the endpoint URL
    const endpoint = `https://businessprofileperformance.googleapis.com/v1/locations/${locationId}:fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries`;

    // Define the headers with the access token
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    };

    // Define the parameters for the API request
    const params = {
      daily_range: {
        start_date: formattedStartDate,
        end_date: formattedEndDate,
      },
      daily_metrics: [
        'reviews_total',
        'reviews_average_rating',
      ],
    };

    // Make the API request with both headers and params
    const response = await axios.get(endpoint, {
      headers,
      params, // Move params here
    });

    // Check if the response is successful
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const data = response.data;
      console.log("Business Profile Performance Data:", data);
    } else if (response.status === 400) {
      // Log the response data for debugging purposes
      console.error("Bad Request:", response.statusText);
      console.error("Response Data:", response.data);
    } else if (response.status === 401) {
      console.error("Unauthorized:", response.statusText);
    } else if (response.status === 403) {
      console.error("Forbidden:", response.statusText);
    } else {
      console.error("HTTP Error:", response.status, response.statusText);
    }

  } catch (error) {
    // Handle other exceptions such as network errors
    console.error("Caught an exception:", error.message);
  }
}

// Invoke the function
fetchBusinessProfilePerformance();
```

I'm trying to connect through Business Profile Performance API, but I'm consistently receiving 400 errors.